# Compare instances of Option[T] avoiding None == None

Tags: scala

Yesterday I was suddenly enlighted and understood how and why people use 'map' method with Option to compare values. Yes, I'm a bit slow, sorry :)

I revised these very nice links and came to the question I would like to ask.

http://twitter.github.com/effectivescala

http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet

In my Lift webapp I have some Option[User] and Option[Server] variables. I'm trying to find out if this User is admin of this Server by the following check

```
if(user.map(_.id) == server.map(_.adminId))
```

But I noticed that in case of 'user' is None and 'server' is also None this check succeeds which is not good for me (if any of them is None I'd like this check to fail). I could add user.isDefined condition but I feel there is more correct way to do it. Could you tell how to accomplish it in Scala way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could do it with pattern matching (which in this case is probably the clearest way):

```
(user, server) match {
  case (Some(user), Some(server)) if user.id == server.adminId =>
    // both ids are matching, handle this case here
  case _ =>
    // no match, handle this case here
}
```

You could also try as a one-liner but here I don't advise it as it's pretty obfuscated:

```
if ( user.flatMap{ user => server.map(_.adminId == user.id) }.getOrElse( false ) ) {
  // both ids are matching, handle this case here
}
else {
  // no match, handle this case here
}
```

Finally, if you only have to handle the case where the ids match (and would just do nothing if there is not), using a for comprehension is not too bad of an option (no pun intended):

```
for ( user <- user; server <- server if user.id == server.adminId ) {
  // both ids are matching, handle this case here
}
```

Comment: the one-liner can be simplified a bit: `user.exists(u => server.exists(_.adminId==u.id))`

Comment: Correct, well spotted. I still don't think a one-liner is a good idea here, even if your version is much more concise (as the intent is still somewhat obfuscated).

Answer (score 24):

I got used to the combination of `exists` / `contains` for this purpose.

When comparing two options of the same type:

```
o1.exists(o2.contains)
```

In your case this can be applied using `map`:

```
user.map(_.id).exists(server.map(_.adminId).contains)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use a for comprehension

```
def isAdmin(server: Option[Server])(user: Option[User]): Boolean = (for {
    s <- server
    u <- user
  } yield (u.id == s.adminId)
).getOrElse(false)
```

The comprehension results in a `Option[Boolean]` from which you `get` the value or `false` if there's no value (the case where any of the options is `None`, as you requested)

*Why curried?*

I made the method curried, so you can define you function for a specific server, and then reuse that to check many users

```
def isMyServerAdmin = isAdmin(Some(myServer)) _

isMyServerAdmin(Some(user1)) = true
isMyServerAdmin(Some(user2)) = false
isMyServerAdmin(None) = false
```

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of [`Option#zip`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/Option.html#zip[A1%3E:A,B](that:Option[B]):Option[(A1,B)]) to work with an `Option` of the tuple user/server:

```
user zip server exists { case (user, server) => user.id == server.adminId }
```

where the behavior of `Option#zip` is:

```
Some(User(id = "hello")) zip Some(Server(adminId = "world"))
// Some((User("hello"), Server("world")))
Some(User(id = "hello")) zip None        // None
None zip Some(Server(adminId = "world")) // None
None zip None                            // None
```

and where [`Option#exists`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/Option.html#exists(p:A=%3EBoolean):Boolean) applies a predicate on the optional tuple produced by `zip`.